# can someone help me with discord.js emotes?

Tags: discord.js

So I wanted my bot to detect if the message is an emote, if it is, detects if it's the :smile: emote if it is for example write :smile: anybody can help me? I'm pretty new to discord.js and would really appreciate it if, someone helped me

Answer (score 0):

You can simply implement multiple if-statements inside your `message` event, for your `:smile:` example it would look like this:

```js
if(message.content === "") return message.channel.send("");
```

You can get the emoji as I displayed in my code, by typing `\:smile:` in a Discord chat. So for  it would be `\:joy:`.